# getting data acknowledgements on the server from the clinet socket.io 1.4.8

Tags: node.js, sockets

On the server side of the Socket I want an acknowledgement from the client:

Server Side message:

```
 function testMessageAck(socketId) {
    var proc = 0; 
    io.to(socketId).emit("check", function() {
        proc = data.result;
        if (proc) {console.log("pid: " + pid + " : " + proc); }   
    });   
}
```

On the Client side I have this:

```
socket.on('check', function(fn) {
        var pid = 42;
        fn({ proc: pid });
    });
```

I have read and re-read the docs, and have seen many examples online that say this should work... but apparently the socket never read the memo, because I get the message that a broadcast can not have a call back! I know the answer is 42, I just need the question!

PS... I'm using this in node js. And on a related note does anyone have a pattern for using a promise for a socket transaction?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the way to do it:

```
function testMessageReturn(socketId) {            
        io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit("check", function(data) {
            proc = data.proc;
            if (proc) {console.log("pid: " + proc); }   
        });   
    }
```

Now I'll try to put that in a Promise... I promise.